# SSIS XML Decryption Message

Tags: encryption, ssis

My SSIS package says it is successful, but when it runs it ends not doing anything (that I can see).

The only thing wrong is this message (that it does not qualify as an error).

```
Description: Failed to decrypt an encrypted XML node because the password was 
not specified or not correct. Package load will attempt to continue without the 
encrypted information
```

I do have a password on my packages, but I don't see anywhere to put the password in when I load the Package into SSIS.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link discusses this problem and its solutions:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918760

Here is the summary from that page.  See that page for the details.

> To resolve this problem, use one of the following methods. The most appropriate method depends on the environment and the reason that the package failed. Reasons that the package may have failed are as follows:
>
> The user account that is used to run the package under SQL Server Agent differs from the original package author.  The user account does not have the required permissions to make connections or to access resources outside the SSIS package.
>
> The package may not run in the following scenarios:
>
> - The current user cannot decrypt secrets from the package. This scenario can occur if the current account or the execution account differs from the original package author, and the package's ProtectionLevel property setting does not let the current user decrypt secrets in the package.
> - A SQL Server connection that uses integrated security fails because the current user does not have the required permissions.
> - File access fails because the current user does not have the required permissions to write to the file share that the connection manager accesses. For example, this scenario can occur with text log providers that do not use a login and a password. This scenario can also occur with any task that depends on the file connection manager, such as a SSIS file system task.
> - A registry-based SSIS package configuration uses the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry keys. The HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry keys are user-specific.
> - A task or a connection manager requires that the current user account has correct permissions.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was attempting to execute a child package that had an encrypted/sensitive parameter.  In the `Execute Package dialog` for the child package there is a field for `Password`.  Since my **project** is encrypted with a password, I had to re-enter my project-level password in the child package's `Password` field.  (I am using Project Deployment Configuration with SQL 2012 configuration, but also Visual Studio/SSDT 2017.)

Answer (score 0):

Before you save the pkg and upload it to the server make sure you have "Save my password" check marked. Test Connection and then in the properties of your SSIS enter password.
 Save and load it to the server. Now in SQL Job Agent when scheduling it, it will ask you for your password.