# SSIS : Warning: Failed to decrypt an encrypted XML node

Tags: xml, encryption, ssis

There are couple of questions similar to this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569140/ssis-xml-decryption-message)). But here is my current situation -

1. I wrote some SSIS packages a while back using a windows account **domain1\first.lastname** with the default protection level set to encryption by user key
2. Now we all got migrated to a new domain **domain2\first.lastname**.
3. So now whenever I open those packages I am getting this error -

> Warning: Failed to decrypt an encrypted XML node. Verify that the
>   project was created by the same user. Project load will attempt to
>   continue without the encrypted information.

Is there a way to open these packages at all ?

Comment: It is not the same user any more (2 domains) thus it might as well be someone trying to hack it. In my OPINION, you would need the old user, otherwise the secrets died with the user.

Answer (score 8):

Open your Project.params file. Enter your password(s) and change them to sensitive False. This will allow you to work and test in Visual Studio.

Read more about SSIS access control here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/security/access-control-for-sensitive-data-in-packages?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This worked for me. Change to sensitive false. Then need to close VS & open it again to get rid of the error/warning. After this, putting sensitive to true will encrypt them again in your username.